# npm config and add more instead of using default.json only

Tags: node.js, npm, config

I read docs from `npm config` but I do not see how to read additional file instead of default config file.

```
config
 default.json
 editable.json
```

I want to add new file is editable.json but how to read data from both *json files?

Thank you so much.